# Rails_admin, remove nested model attributes from form while creating model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, mongoid, rails-admin

I have started to use Rails_Admin gem and it is great. However, there is one issue. I am using Mongoid and I have created my models:

```
class Client
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :email, type: String

   has_many :favourites, dependent: :destroy
end

class Service
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :name, type: String
   has_many :favourites, dependent: :destroy
end

class Favourite
   include Mongoid::Document

   belongs_to :client
   belongs_to :service
 end
```

I have created some data by using `seed.rb`. When I open my admin page and try to create new `Client`, after `Clients` attribute fields, it shows me multiselect form to add `Favourites` and shows me `Favourites` of all other `Clients`.

How to remove this from creation form? I have read that I need to add `inverse_of` for all my classes associations, but it is not removing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model:

```
class Client
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :email, type: String
    has_many :favourites, dependent: :destroy

    rails_admin do
     edit do
       exclude_fields :favourites
     end
    end
end
```

Source: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Railsadmin-DSL#configuring-fields

Comment: throws me an error `NoMethodError  undefined method default for #<Client:0x0000000d569598>`

Comment: This solution brings new question. I have removed nested form during the creation of model. If I want to something like `add Favourite for this Client` in `edit` page of my model, what do I need to do?